# How to configure nginx ssl to support ie6

Tags: ssl, nginx, internet-explorer-6

I configure nginx ssl, but can not support ie6. see the nginx debug log

```
2017/07/28 14:00:16 [crit] 5923#0: *25500 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1417D18C:SSL routines:tls_process_client_hello:version too low) while SSL handshaking, client: myip, server: 0.0.0.0:443
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be SSL version, you should add SSLv1 and use ciphers of this version.